# optional parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Just new to typescript in an angular context. Can you mark properties as optional in the example below? How would you recommend specifying a nav item has no children? With regular JS I would usually rely on a falsey value to check if the object has `children` property. But in Typescript is it best practice to initialise an empty array? What about other primitive properties that may/may not have values?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children: NavItem[];
}

const data: NavItem[] = [
  {
    key: "dashboard",
    target: "dashboard",
    text: "Dashboard",
    children: []
  },
  {
    key: "sales",
    target: "sales",
    text: "Sales"
  }
];

@Injectable()
export class NavService {
  getNav() {
    return data;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, it's very easy to mark a property as optional, you add `?` after it:

```
class NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children?: NavItem[];
}
```

Alternatively you can also use a union with `null` or `undefined`:

```
class NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children: NavItem[] | undefined;
}
```

With that being said, you misunderstood something very important, this is wrong:

```
const data: NavItem[] = [
  {
    key: "dashboard",
    target: "dashboard",
    text: "Dashboard",
    children: []
  },
  {
    key: "sales",
    target: "sales",
    text: "Sales"
  }
];
```

`data` is **not** an array of `NavItem` items, in order to get that you'll need to create instances of `NavItem` using the `new` keyword, for example:

```
const data: NavItem[] = [
  Object.assign(new NavItem(), {
    key: "dashboard",
    target: "dashboard",
    text: "Dashboard",
    children: []
  }),
  Object.assign(new NavItem(), {
    key: "sales",
    target: "sales",
    text: "Sales"
  })
];
```

The compiler doesn't complain about doing that because typescript is [based on structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) and the two types share the same structure.
But it's easy to see why it's wrong by adding methods to `NavItem`:

```
class NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children?: NavItem[];

  getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }
}
```

Now try this with your code:

```
console.log(data[0].getKey());
```

And you'll end up with:

> Uncaught TypeError: data[0].getKey is not a function

You should even get a compilation error saying that `getKey` is missing in your array items.

If you only intend to use `NavItem` as data objects then it doesn't really matter, but you should just use interfaces or type aliases instead as they don't get compiled to js and you avoid redundant memory usage:

```
interface NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children?: NavItem[];
}
```

---

#### Edit

After a comment from @Zze I've decided to add a simple constructor that uses the "power" of `Object.assign`:

```
class NavItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
  target: string;
  children?: NavItem[];

  constructor(data?: NavItem) {
      if (data) {
          Object.assign(this, data);
      }
  }
}
```

then:

```
new NavItem({
    key: "sales",
    target: "sales",
    text: "Sales"
})
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't suggest the creation of a `constructor()` for `NavItem` ?

Comment: @Zze Was just trying to keep it to minimum change and to focus on the problem. Also, in this case it makes sense to use `Object.assign` in this manner instead of having the usual boilerplate constructor as it won't do anything other than assigning values to the members.

Comment: @Zze Check my revised answer, I added a constructor that used `Object.assign`